# How to make the title bar, minimize button and maximize button invisible on a web page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing a project on an online examination site. I wanted to make the title bar, minimize button and windows taskbar of the browser invisible when a candidate is clicking to attend the  exam. Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: can i take it as you want to make webpage full screen.

Comment: ss..I want to make a online exam app..i want to disable all the clicking events and searching options..

Comment: I dont think what you want to acheive is possible. Plus, your title has javascript but you have tagged this with php

Comment: then in which is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work for Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE 11+.

The below code is implemented using fullscreen API. It also toggle the fullscreen using user interaction. You can also detect the current status of fullscreen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.fullscreen)? "on" : "not ";
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.mozFullScreen)? "on" : "not ";
}, false);

document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.webkitIsFullScreen)? "on" : "not ";
}, false);

document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function () {
    fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.msFullscreenElement)? "on" : "not ";
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleFullScreen();">
Open in Full Screen Window</a>
<p>Fullscreen state: I'm <b id="fullscreenState"> not </b> fullscreen</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you are using this for online examination follow below steps

1. as by default status is 'no fullscreen'.
2. After making page to fullscreen start tracking user interaction with browser fullscreen using this status. If user changes back to normal, then discard user from giving exam/make as malpractice, etc.
3. All you have to do is check the request_access for fullscreen.

> ref:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API